# Hamlet route for OptionalSubsite

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I am using an OptionalSubsite as shown here: https://gist.github.com/snoyberg/8d85d41c5b4d0da002ae

How can I create a hamlet link/route to a file that is served in this subsite?

```
$if servingOptionalSite
    <a href="@{StaticR (routeToOptionalFile)}">Docs
```

I can not rely on template haskell functions such as `staticFiles` to generate routes for the contents of the served folder because it is not always existent, hence OptionalSubsite.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with

```hs
optionalRouteR = OptionalRoute $ StaticRoute ["index.html"] []
```

which can then be used in hamlet

```
<a href="@{StaticR optionalRouteR}">Docs
```